# After changing the wrong canonical URL, the Google cache still points to the previous canonical URL

Tags: seo, googlebot, canonical-url, rel-canonical

We have accidentally used a wrong canonical URL and Google cached the page with the wrong URLs data. When we found this and updated the correct canonical URL, it still points to the same old wrong canonical URL's data in the cache. When I search the the URL with `info:` in Google, I get the wrong canonical URL in the search results.

I have tried reindexing the page, still the same issue is coming up.

How can I make Google index the updated content?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that this is happening is that say we have page.html, and on that page is rel canonical="page1.html", Google will now likely deindex page.html and index page1.html. And it will likely also stop crawling page.html.

As a result, if you change the canonical tag on page.html to page2.html, Google is no longer crawling that page and so it can't update the new canonical tag.

The best solution to this problem in my opinion is to either 301 redirect (permanent) page1.html to page2.html, or to add rel canonical="page2.html" on page1.html. This will correctly tell Google to index the new canonical page that you want indexed.